# For Loop and Sequential Timeout

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, timeout

I'm trying to sequentially print some data from an array. The array has this format: ((text,delay),(text,delay))
I want each timeout to start after the next timeout finishes. I've gotten this far, but I'm pretty stumped now. The timeouts all start at the same time with this code.

```
 <script>
    var data = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>'); 
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        texttime = data[i];
         (function (x) {
            setTimeout(function () {document.write(x[0]) +"<br>"}, x[1]*1000);
        })(texttime);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: stop and think about why they all go off at same time. Loop doesn't wait for each `setTimeout` to execute, it runs in a few thousandths of a second. So you need to keep adding the delays to stagger the start times

Comment: Right, fair enough. But I'd really prefer if each timer started after the previous had finished.

Comment: few months back i was searching for this :-/ , great question :) +1 from me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop doesn't quite work here, because you can't wait in a for loop in JavaScript. But you can use recursion to iterate a collection, too, and since setTimeout uses a callback, you can implement a kind of recursive callback: You can set a timeout for the first thing you want to do and then in the callback for that you can set a timeout for the next thing and so on, until you reach the end of the array.

Here's how you could do it:

```
(function () {

    var contentIndex = 0, timeoutIndex = 1;
    var data = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>');

    timeoutIterate(0, exists, consume, timeout);

    function timeoutIterate (i, conditionFn, consumerFn, timeoutFn) {
        if (conditionFn(i)) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                consumerFn(i);
                timeoutIterate(i + 1, conditionFn, consumerFn, timeoutFn);
            }, timeoutFn(i));
        }
    }

    function timeout (i) {
        return data[i][timeoutIndex] * 1000;
    }

    function content (i) {
        return data[i][contentIndex];
    }

    function exists (i) {
        return i < data.length;
    }

    function consume (i) {
        document.write(content(i));
    }

}());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to execute operations in sequences by specific interval. I think this will help you. I updated my answer, json_encode of your $data array will be in following js array.
**update**
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aw2e1qez/1/)

```
var data =  [
    ["Peter is getting ready for work",20],
    ["Peter is on the train",10],
    ["Peter left the station and is walking to work",10]
];

sequence_operate(data,0);

function sequence_operate(arr,index){   
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").append("<div>"+arr[index][0]+"   :   <span class='green'>"+arr[index][1]+" minute</span>");
        if(index<arr.length)
            sequence_operate(arr,index+1);
    },arr[index][1]*100);
}
```

**original**
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aw2e1qez/)

```
    var data =  [
    {"value":"this is first"},
    {"value":"this is second"},
    {"value":"this is third"},
    {"value":"this is forth"},
    {"value":"this is fifth"}
];

sequence_operate(data,0,500);

function sequence_operate(arr,index,interval){   
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").append("<div>"+arr[index].value);
        if(index<arr.length)
            sequence_operate(arr,index+1,interval);
    },interval);
}
```

Comment: Yeah! like that, but I'd liked to tie each time to specific text. EX: (("Peter is getting ready for work",20 minutes),("Peter is on the train",10 minutes),("Peter left the station and is walking to work, 5 minutes))

Comment: I want to see your array structure, can you show me your vardump output of $data array please.

Comment: From php: 'array_push($data,array($gender."is eating",15));' It's just a list of actions and a time associated with each action. I'd like to display each action as they take place. This may not be the best way of doing that, though. I'm no expert at javascript.

Comment: I've updated my answer, is that what you want? [UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/aw2e1qez/1/)